# The double sum $\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{m} (-1)^{i+j} {m \choose i} {n \choose j} {i+j \choose i} =0~ \mbox{or}~1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

For non-negative integers $m$ and $n$, the double sum $$\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{m} (-1)^{i+j} {m \choose i} {n \choose j} {i+j \choose i}$$
can be checked to be 0 or 1. How can one show this by hand, along with the conditions on $m$ and $n$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you get anywhere?  A little computer experiment suggests that the sum is $1$ precisely when $n=m$.  (This true when $1\leq n,m\leq25$.)

Comment: @saulspatz,  Thanks, yes you are right, you may see my solution posted below.

Comment: Seems like you answer your own question...chill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from

$$\sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^{p+q}
{n\choose p} {m\choose q} {p+q\choose q}$$

we write

$$\sum_{p=0}^n (-1)^{p} {n\choose p}
\sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^{m-q}
{m\choose q} {p+m-q\choose m-q}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n (-1)^{p} {n\choose p}
(-1)^m [z^m] (1+z)^{p+m} \sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^{q}
{m\choose q} z^q (1+z)^{-q}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n (-1)^{p} {n\choose p}
(-1)^m [z^m] (1+z)^{p+m}
\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^m
\\ = (-1)^m [z^m]
\sum_{p=0}^n (-1)^{p} {n\choose p}
 (1+z)^{p}
\\ = (-1)^m [z^m] (1-(1+z))^n
= (-1)^{m+n} [z^m] z^n
= (-1)^{m+n} \delta_{n,m} = \delta_{n,m}.$$

Comment: Very nice and wonderful !

Comment: Thank you. I hope it proves useful.

Comment: You have not defined z.

Comment: We are working with [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients) here. For another example and additional documentation consult this [MSE link A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245489/) and this [MSE link B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277706/)  by Markus Scheuer.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Would you mind to look at *[this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278355)*? Maybe you could help us to find a solution. Best regards,

Answer (score 7):

The Laguerre Polynomials are defined as $$L_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{j} \frac{{n \choose j}}{j!} x^J,~~~(1)$$ these are well known to follow the orthogonality condition as
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} L_m(x)~ L_n(x)~ dx=\delta_{m,n}~,~~~~(2)$$ where $\delta_{m,n}$ is the  Kroneckor delta function, If we insert (1) in (2), we get
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m} \sum_{0}^{n} (-1)^{i+j} \frac{{m \choose i}}{i!} \frac{{n \choose j}}{j!} x^{i+j} e^{-x}~ dx= \delta_{m,n}.$$ Finally, $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^k  e^{-x}~dx= k!$, leads to
$$\sum_{i=0}^{m} \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{i+j} {m \choose i} {n \choose j} {i+j \choose i} = \delta_{m,n}.$$ Hence the result.

Comment: This is a much clearer solution. It lacks a proof of (1) but this can readily be found.

Answer (score 3):

This is a slight variation of @MarkoRiedels nice answer. We  use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n }{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain for integral $m,n\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{p=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\sum_{q=0}^m(-1)^{p+q}\binom{n}{p}\binom{m}{q}\binom{p+q}{q}}\\
> &=\sum_{p=0}^n\binom{n}{p}(-1)^p\sum_{q=0}^m\binom{m}{q}(-1)^q[z^q](1+z)^{p+q}\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^0]\sum_{p=0}^n\binom{n}{p}(-1)^p(1+z)^p\sum_{q=0}^m\binom{m}{q}\left(-\frac{1+z}{z}\right)^q\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^0]\sum_{p=0}^n\binom{n}{p}(-1)^p(1+z)^p\left(1-\frac{1+z}{z}\right)^m\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^m[z^m]\sum_{p=0}^n\binom{n}{p}(-1)^p(1+z)^p\tag{5}\\
> &=(-1)^m[z^m]\left(1-(1+z)\right)^n\\
> &=(-1)^{m+n}[z^m]z^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[[m=n]]}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (3) we do some rearrangements and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we do some simplifications and apply the rule from (3) again.
- In (6) we use *[Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)*.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I hope it helps clarify the method that was used in the two combinatorial proofs so that we have a more readable page. To be precise the argument to the $[z^0]$ coefficient extractor on line three is not a formal power series, so for this to hold we must use the definition in terms of residues $${n\choose k} = [z^k] (1+z)^n = \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^n.$$ The proof as I posted it uses formal power series only (no pole at zero).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: You're welcome and thanks for the credit. I also hope, it helps to clarify the used technique. Thank you for the additional information which also makes the change of order of summation of the inner sum in your first line plausible.